# How to scale the image and keep the ratio automatically in opencv when window resize

Tags: c++, opencv

The namedWindow function provides a 'CV_WINDOW_NORMAL' option, but when I resize the window, the image is just clipped. How to scale the image automatically in a simple way?

Comment: use CV_WINDOW_NORMAL instead

Comment: Well I made a mistake. I mean CV_WINDOW_NORMAL.

Comment: rotten apples seem to have that problem

Comment: @berak I'm on OS X 10.9. OpenCV was installed by macports, with both of C++ and python bindings.

Comment: sorry, no idea. just noted a lot of apple users with this problem  lately (while win/linux seems to be unaffected)